# Integrating a defined Function of 2 variables

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have defined a function p(V,T):

```
p[V_, T_] = (R*T/(V - b)) - (a/(V^2))
```

And then I used:

```
Integrate[p[V, T], {V, V1, V2}]
```

And there is no output. What I have done wrong?
Obs.: I have also tried `dintt`

Comment: btw, what is `dintt` ? And it will help to say which version you are using.

Comment: esc dinnt esc -> writes the integral to be done symbolic. I'm using Mathematica 12

Comment: when you are going to $\int$ something like $1/x$ , MMA will consider the complex number, so it will be much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

p[V_, T_] = (R*T/(V - b)) - (a/(V^2));
```

Include an assumption

```
Assuming[V2 > V1, Integrate[p[V, T], {V, V1, V2}]]

(* ConditionalExpression[
 a (-(1/V1) + 1/V2) + 
  R T (-Log[-b + V1] + Log[-b + V2]), (V1 > 
     0 && (V1 > Re[b] || V2 < Re[b] || Re[b] < 0 || 
      b ∉ Reals)) || (V2 < 
     0 && (V2 < Re[b] || V1 > Re[b] || b ∉ Reals))] *)
```

Additional assumptions provide a simpler result

```
Assuming[V2 > V1 && Element[{a, b}, Reals],
 Integrate[p[V, T], {V, V1, V2}]]

(* ConditionalExpression[a (-(1/V1) + 1/V2) + R T Log[(b - V2)/(b - V1)], 
 b < V1 && (V2 < 0 || V1 > 0)] *)
```

Comment: Worked!!!! THANKS

Answer (score 2):

> And there is no output

sometimes when Integrate seems to hang or take long time, use the option `GenerateConditions -> False`

```
ClearAll[p, V, T, V1, V2, R, a, b];
p[V_, T_] := (R*T/(V - b)) - (a/(V^2));
Integrate[p[V, T], {V, V1, V2}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> I still got no answer

I do not know why on your system you get no answer. For me, it works right away. Here is screen shot

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Using V12

Comment: I still got no answer

Comment: @IamZack I posted screen shot. I do not know why it does not work for you. Try with clean kernel just in case.

Comment: Thanks man, but I think my Mathematica needs me to do a assumption as in the answer below.